# Film Post Sound Design Newbie needs help

Tags: film-sound-design

Hi there, I'm a film student coming to the end of my course and have tinkered with sound design a little, although my course doesn't really address it as much I would have hoped.  I have access to a copy of Nuendo 4 on a PC and that's pretty much it.

Can anyone please recommend anywhere on line that I can begin looking into the basic's?

Also is Nuendo worth learning? I'm a PC user (I have and do use Mac's, I just prefer a PC)... aside form messing around with the programme myself is there an on-line research of tutorials specifically designed with film post in mind and not just music production as I keep coming across?

Finally within a modest budget suggestions on cheaply building a home set up, what basic to pick up or on-line examples?

Realise this is a lot to ask,

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot answer all of your questions, but I will try to do so with some of them.

First of all, Nuendo is a pretty good tool. It is somewhat more complex and difficult to learn than, say, Ableton Live, but in the end it is not that important what you use, as long as you use it well. I prefer PCs as well, and I found out that Ableton Live is the best DAW for PCs out there. But if you have access to Nuendo then by all means go ahead and learn to use it. Someday it will come in handy. And it will make learning another DAW easier for you, as they all run on similar principles.

As for tutorials, if you don't have much money to spend at this point the best solution is to check your school library, as Jamie pointed out. Otherwise just go to Amazon and look for some film post books.

Regarding your setup, you can get a decent audio interface and a pair of near field monitors. If you're on a budget, M-audio makes really cheap interfaces called Fast Track Pro or Ultra. For the monitors you can get a pair of Adam, KRK or M-Audio ones at great prices.

Good luck with your endeavors. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a great starting point though, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

hit up your school library and borrow all the post sound books they have.
they can be expensive once you finish school and don't have free access to them anymore

Answer (score 0):

Im very much a noob myself, but I really cannot praise enough my Beyer 770Pros. I can wear them for HOURS comfortably, then are built well, great for foley and location work. And from experience, I think a great pair of headphones is better than an OK pair of speakers in an ok room.

I have lots of other ideas for DAWs and kit, but I think headphones are essential.

Comment: Don't think I could personally go back to headphones after monitors, even those in an OK room - headphones sound gross and flat to my ears now, but that's just my opinion.  I also find that headphones seem to skew how our ears naturally perceive the equal loudness curve and frequency masking/balance we experience.  There's definitely something to be said though for allowing waveforms to fully develop as they propagate through air.